# My seconds variable is not storing properly

Tags: c++

As the title says my seconds variable is not storing properly and im unsure as to why. I tried inserting a cout statement after the user inputs on line 8, but for some reason it's not storing i.e the output would be -1.75474e+4. Thank you :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double readSeconds()
{
    double seconds;
    cout << "Enter the time (in seconds)" << endl;
    cin >> seconds;

    //value less than zero
    while (seconds < 0) {
        cout << "The time must be zero or more" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the time (in seconds)" << endl;
        cin >> seconds;
    }
    return seconds;
}
double calculateEarthDistance(double seconds)
{
    const double gravityEarth = 9.8;
    double earthDistance = 0.5 * gravityEarth * pow(seconds, 2);
    return earthDistance;
}
double calculateMoonDistance(double seconds)
{
    const double gravityMoon = 1.6;
    double moonDistance = 0.5 * gravityMoon * pow(seconds, 2);
    return moonDistance;
}

//The displayResults function MUST NOT call readSeconds, calculateEarthDistance, or calculateMoonDistance.
void displayResults(double seconds, double earthDistance, double moonDistance)
{

    cout << "The object traveled " << fixed << setprecision(4) << earthDistance << fixed << setprecision(2) << " meters in " << seconds << " on Earth." << endl;
    cout << "The object traveled " << fixed << setprecision(4) << moonDistance << fixed << setprecision(2) << " meters in " << seconds << " on Moon." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    if (1) { //when true
        double seconds;
        seconds == readSeconds();
        cout << seconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            exit(0);
        }
        double earthDistance = calculateEarthDistance(seconds);
        double moonDistance = calculateMoonDistance(seconds);
        displayResults(seconds, earthDistance, moonDistance);
    }

} //end program
```

Comment: == is used for a comparison. = is assignment. `seconds == readSeconds();` compares the value of seconds with the result returned from readSeconds() then it throws away the result of the comparison. A modern compiler should warn you about this in many cases.

Comment: turn on compiler warnings and pay attention to them (https://godbolt.org/z/x7rzss)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used equivalent operator(==), instead of assign operator(=)

```cpp
seconds == readSeconds(); // bad
seconds = readSeconds();  // good
```

Comment: Surprised no compiler warning, "statement has no effect".  Perhaps there was...

Comment: @PaulSanders gcc needs `-Wall` clang warns with defaults (https://godbolt.org/z/x7rzss).

Comment: @idclev463035818 Good old clang.  That's how it should be, it's a common mistake.  And the other way round too, for that matter.

Comment: @PaulSanders I am a gcc fan boy by origin, but I encountered lots of warnings that gcc needs some help to emit them recently, so I am starting to believe clang has something. Maybe `-Wall` is just too common